Migrate from RestTemplate to WebFlux
I have this RestTemplate which I want to migrate to WebFlux client:
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
ResponseEntity<Envelope> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Envelope.class);

I tried this:
Boolean webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .exchangeToMono(res -> Mono.just(res.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)))
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .block();

I'm not clear how I can get the response and read the response as JAVA DTO. Do you know how I have to implement his code?

To make a request and retrieve a response you need to call the retrieve function on the WebClient. Then you can parse the response Body with bodyToMono. It's important to know that Mono is a single Object and Flux are Collection-Types
Envelope envelope = WebClient.builder()
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .exchangeToMono(res -> Mono.just(res.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)))
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Envelope.class)
                .block();

There's also a nice example and explanation on this page: https://www.baeldung.com/webflux-webclient-parameters
But I would suggest you to structure your code a little bit more. For example, as you're using Spring Boot think about using that WebClientBuilder to create a WebClient as Bean, that WebClient would be configured to have a base url (https://www.ecb.europa.eu). Then you have a service where you inject that WebClient and make a call to receive your Envelope. Something like this would enable you to use the same WebCLient for different calls to the same host:
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

@Configuration
public class RestConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebClient ecbEuropaWebClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().tcpConfiguration(
                (client) -> client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000).doOnConnected(
                        (connection) -> connection.addHandlerLast(
                                new ReadTimeoutHandler(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))));
        ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
        return webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl("https://www.ecb.europa.eu")
                .clientConnector(connector)
                .build();
    }
}

@Service
public class EcbEuropaService {
    @Autowired
    private WebClient ecbEuropaWebClient;

    public Envelope getEnvelope() {
        return ecbEuropaWebClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml").build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).retrieve().bodyToMono(Envelope.class).block();
    }
}


I have multiple objects into Envelope.  Also can I remove block() code?

If you have a Collection like List you need to use bodyToFlux. You can remove the block if you are using Springs Reactive Stack, if you are using a classic Servlet Stack you need the block

One more additional question. In a classical spring boot application which one rest client provides more benefits RestTemplate or WebFlux?

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. For example I found it very challenging to add OpenID Flows to RestTemplate, but with WebClient it was pretty easy. Also I think WebClient will be more future proof. There’s also a good comparison here: https://medium.com/@kmrpushkar09/spring-webclient-vs-resttemplate-whats-better-in-2023-99844f649b53

Also you could write an abstraction layer which enables you to very flexible change the used Technologies. But depending on your use case that could be overkill. There’s also Apache HttpClient which is worth a look.
